# Appropriate sample statistics to provide a reliable estimator for an Erlang-like parent population

Tags: distributions, estimation

We would like to measure (in near real-time) the completion latency of requests to our queue-based system.  The volume of inbound requests is sufficiently high that we would like to sample/aggregate and report sample statistics back on regular (3 second basis).  Our problem is that we don't know what statistics to capture from the sample and how to combine them to provide a reliable set of estimators for the parent population.

We know that the distribution of the parent population is not normal, we suspect the closest is a gamma function, e.g. the Erlang distribution.

Comment: I'm going to migrate this question to the stats.SE site. I expect there will be many more people there who will be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not totally clear to me what to want to do with your data.

If you are trying to estimate the two parameters of a Gamma (or an Erlang) distritibution then the number of observations, the sum of the observations, and the product of the observations (or equivalently the sum of the logarithms) together are [sufficient statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Gamma_distribution).

As for the estimation itself, there is no elementary solution.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Parameter_estimation) has some suggestions or you could use a Bayesian methods with a [conjugate family](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.157.5540&rep=rep1&type=pdf) prior density proportional to 
$$\frac{p^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda q}}{\Gamma(\alpha)^r \lambda^{-\alpha s}}$$ where the prior hyperparamenters $p$,$q$,$r$,$s$ become the posterior hyperparameters $p\prod_{i=1}^n x_i$, $q + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, $r+n$, $s+n$ respectively.